# CircularProgressIndicator not displayed in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Im trying to display the `CircularProgressIndicator` in my flutter app on click of button but it does not render the circular progress bar, but as soon as I change the code to use `LinearProgressBar` the progress bar comes without any issue. So wanted to know is there any special setting which I need to display the circular loading indicator?

**Works**

```
if (_isFetching) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Center(
      child: new SizedBox(
        width: 40.0,
        height: 40.0,
        child: const LinearProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.black)),
  ));
}
```

**Do not work**

```
if (_isFetching) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Center(
      child: new SizedBox(
        width: 40.0,
        height: 40.0,
        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.black)),
  ));
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Check if _isFetching is true or not.

Comment: That is always true otherwise linear indicator should not display

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the progress bar's value color is different from the parent widget's background color. Try this:

```
if (_isFetching) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 40.0,
        height: 40.0,
        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red))),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) here. You are using backgroundColor property which only defines background color of indicator and not the type of indicator. I'm using `null` for Indeterminate type. You can use `valueColor`[[doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ProgressIndicator/valueColor.html)] property to change the color of indicator. Here is simple code and it works fine.

```
if (_isFetching) {
          return new Scaffold(
              body: new Center(
            child: new SizedBox(
                width: 40.0,
                height: 40.0,
                child:
                    const CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: null,
        strokeWidth: 2.0,
      )),
          ));
        }
```

Comment: The issue is not the color or the storkewidth because you can also create parameterless constructor where the default color is primary pallet color so the issue here is not color or strokewidth

Comment: okay i get that. May be you should use `Container()` instead of `SizedBox`